# Rails add validation to check number of instances of a model based on attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a rails model including the following attributes:

- `monitorable_type` (3 possible values : black/blue/red)
- `monitorable_id`.

I want to add a validation to prevent a new record from being saved only if `monitorable_type` is 'red' and there are already X (for example 5) instances of that model with the same `monitorable_id` as the one being created.

Can't figure out how to do it properly, thanks!

Comment: You can use a validator class: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#validates-with

Comment: Also can use a scoped uniqueness validator, https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness